# Scroll to active accordion panel without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

**The situation:**
I work on a web application which consists of a map and a a sidebar. Within the sidebar an accordion is given with 20 panels. When the user selects a point on the map, the relevant accordion panel is opened.

**The problem:**
When the user selects a point, not only the panel should be opened, but it should scroll to the activated panel.

**What I already tried:**
I have been searching for a solution for hours, but either the proposed solutions work with jQuery (which I can't use) or different scroll options that are based on the ID of an html element like `document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();` which I can't use, because the panels are div elements with a class and not an id attribute. I tried to use the scrollIntoView() option for document.getElementsByClassName() but it didn't work.

**The code:**
I work on html, css and JavaScript code, I don't use jQuery. My implemented accordion is within a div with a id ("description"), the accordion itself consists of the header `<button class="accordion">` and the panels `<div class="accordion-panel">`

**The question:** 
Any idea how I can scroll to a specific div element (from 20 div elements that all belong to the same class, but can be addressed by their certain ID/number (not the html id attribute))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a class which states which accordion-panel is active. If that's true, this solution should work. Otherwise, post some of the HTML you have.

To get the desired element, you should use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), which accepts multiple classes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-panel active')
```

If you are sure there is only one of those elements, you should be able to do the following:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-panel active')[0].scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that did the trick!!! As I know via the ID of the clicked point which panel should be activated, I could scroll down to it with document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-panel')[theID].scrollIntoView();

Comment: Nice! You can always set this answer to accepted if it helped you, so it will help others in the future! Good luck with the non-jQuery programming, which is pretty awesome!